# Fastest way to find a row in excel range using Excel Macro VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have got an excel spreadsheet (sheet2) with records of count around 1 Million. I am iterating these records and for each iteration I am comparing a row of selected columns against another range of around 2000 records which is in sheet1.

```
rangeA = 1 Million rows 'Sheet2
rangeB = 2000 rows 'Sheet1

With sheet1
For Each row In rangeA.Columns.Rows

   For Each rangeBRow In rangeB.Columns.Rows
     If (.Cells(rangeBRow.Row,1).Value = CName And .Cells(rangeBRow.Row,2).Value = LBL ... ) Then
     ' Do something cool... set some cell value in sheet2
     Exit For
     End If
   Next rangeBRow

Next row
End With
```

My problem with the above code is that it is taking forever to complete the execution. Is there some other fastest and a quick way to find a row against a range of rows in excel macro other than iterating a million records for 2000 rows?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: load everything into arrays and then compare the references instead of ranges

Comment: Great. Will try, and be back here

Comment: Create a dictionary object and load it up from your 1M rows, using the two identifiers as the key (join them to create a composite value)

Comment: If you could give a code example it would be of great help

Comment: Are you comparing all values in the rows, or just some?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

12 seconds to check 5k rows against 200k:

```
Sub Compare()

    Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range
    Dim dict As Object, rw As Range
    Dim a As Application, tmp As String

    Set a = Application
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    Set rngA = Sheet1.Range("A2:F200000")
    Set rngB = Sheet1.Range("K2:P5000")

    For Each rw In rngA.Rows
        'Create a key from the entire row and map to row
        ' If your rows are not unique you'll have to do a bit more work here
        ' and use an array for the key value(s)
        dict.Add Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rw.Value)), Chr(0)), rw.Row
    Next rw

    For Each rw In rngB.Rows
        'does this row match one in range A?
        tmp = Join(a.Transpose(a.Transpose(rw.Value)), Chr(0))
        If dict.exists(tmp) Then
            rw.Cells(1).Offset(0, -1).Value = dict(tmp)
        End If
    Next rw

End Sub
```

Comment: Getting back to you a bit late but i want to thank you for your help! It was life saver. Thanks again.

Comment: how much faster is this than simply iterating down rngA.Rows and looking for (With rng.find) each row in rngB.rows?

Comment: I don't know but you could easily test.